# Can HTML5 <br> tag have attributes?

Tags: html

[W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_attributes.asp) says that "All HTML elements can have attributes", so can `<br>` tag have attributes?

Comment: Well, why don't you try `<br style="display:none">` and see what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use br tag element to specific the id or any other css style, or custom attribute, and the modification you could use on either JavaScript or even  on the size you broke the line.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) for documentation on the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Br tag supports global attributes and event attributes.

Global attributes :- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp

Event attributes :- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp